# What to fill in for letter from current employer when I am still a student applying for a research project in Canada?

Tags: working-visas, canada

I'm applying for a work visa for as a graduate student in Computer Science for a research project in Canada. They ask me several things and one which I can't provide :

> **Document: Letter from Current Employer**
>
> You must provide a letter from your current employer or proof of
> annotated pay stubs from your employer. This is used to confirm the
> details of your financial profile
>
> Financial profile details include your job status (full‑time or
> part‑time), how long you have worked for the company, your occupation,
> etc.

I don't have current employer, I'm only doing a research project and I'm still a student until September. What should I fill in ? A letter from my tutor in Canada ? Nothing or a pdf letter saying that I don't have any current employer and I'm waiting for this visa to work for him ?

Comment: Have you had any advice from your university? They will have experience in this.

Comment: @user16259 No ... :/ I will ask the international office tomorrow

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica , did you find a solution?

Comment: @user_007 letter from my tutor was the solution

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica  But then this is similar to the other points, which are: `Employment Reference Letter` and
`Employment Records` .. right?

Comment: Yes, it worked for me at least. 2 years ago

Comment: Well they still contact your employer if you have provided them with letter of employment ?